# Fetch and render component in React-Native

Tags: react-native

I want to display swiper in view component after fetch finish,
this is my code.

```
    renderItem = ({ item }) => {
        return (
            <Swiper showsButtons={false} showsPagination={false} autoplay={true}>
                <TouchableOpacity onPress={this.GetItem.bind(this, item.info.title)}>
                    <ImageBackground
                        resizeMode='cover'
                        source={{ uri : "https://www.tes.com/image/" + item.info.banner}}
                        style={{width: 453, height: 230}}
                        >
                        <View>
                            <Text>
                                {item.info.category_name}
                            </Text>
                            <Text>
                                {item.info.title}
                            </Text>
                            <Text>
                                {moment(new Date(item.info.created_at * 1000)).format('dddd, D MMMM YYYY hh:mm')} WIB
                            </Text>
                        </View>
                    </ImageBackground>
                </TouchableOpacity>
                <TouchableOpacity onPress={this.GetItem.bind(this, item.news.title)}>
                    <ImageBackground
                        resizeMode='cover'
                        source={{ uri : "https://www.tes.com/image/" + item.news.banner}}
                        style={{width: 453, height: 230}}
                        >
                        <View>
                            <Text>
                                {item.news.category_name}
                            </Text>
                            <Text>
                                {item.news.title}
                            </Text>
                            <Text>
                                {moment(new Date(item.news.created_at * 1000)).format('dddd, D MMMM YYYY hh:mm')} WIB
                            </Text>
                        </View>
                    </ImageBackground>
                </TouchableOpacity>
                <TouchableOpacity onPress={this.GetItem.bind(this, item.tips.title)}>
                    <ImageBackground
                        resizeMode='cover'
                        source={{ uri : "https://www.tes.com/image/" + item.tips.banner}}
                        style={{width: 453, height: 230}}
                        >
                        <View>
                            <Text>
                                {item.tips.category_name}
                            </Text>
                            <Text>
                                {item.tips.title}
                            </Text>
                            <Text>
                                {moment(new Date(item.tips.created_at * 1000)).format('dddd, D MMMM YYYY hh:mm')} WIB
                            </Text>
                        </View>
                    </ImageBackground>
                </TouchableOpacity>
                <TouchableOpacity onPress={this.GetItem.bind(this, item.story.title)}>
                    <ImageBackground
                        resizeMode='cover'
                        source={{ uri : "https://www.tes.com/image/" + item.story.banner}}
                        style={{width: 453, height: 230}}
                        >
                        <View>
                            <Text>
                                {item.story.category_name}
                            </Text>
                            <Text>
                                {item.story.title}
                            </Text>
                            <Text>
                                {moment(new Date(item.story.created_at * 1000)).format('dddd, D MMMM YYYY hh:mm')} WIB
                            </Text>
                        </View>
                    </ImageBackground>
                </TouchableOpacity>
            </Swiper>
        )
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        return fetch('https://www.tes.com/site/load-headline')
          .then((response) => response.json())
          .then((responseJson) => {
            this.setState({
              isLoading: false,
              dataSource: responseJson.data,
            }, function() {
              // In this block you can do something with new state.
            });
          })
          .catch((error) => {
            console.error(error);
          });
      }

render() {
    return (
            {
                this.state.isLoading ? <ActivityIndicator /> : false
            }
            <View style={{flexDirection: "column", padding: 10}}>
                {this.renderItem}
            </View>
          )
         }
```

But it is not working.
Before it, I use FlatList then use its property renderItem and it works.
But now I dont want to use FlatList, I need to use Swiper.
So how can I render the swiper to view after fetch complete?

Please help

Answer (score 0):

```
render() {
return (
        <View>
        {
            this.state.isLoading ? (<ActivityIndicator />) : (<View 
             style={{flexDirection: "column", padding: 10}}>
            {this.renderItem}
        </View>)
        }
        </View>
      )
     }
```

It may be work.

Comment: not working, there is warning : "functions are not valid as a React child. This may happen if you return a Component instead of <Component /> from render. Or maybe you meant to call this function rather than return it."

Answer (score 0):

The Conditional operator is not in good position.

No small parentheses are required in the return. You must specify the area of the view.

```js
return this.state.isLoading === true ? (
      <View style={{ flex: 1, alignItems: "center", justifyContent: "center" }}>
        <ActivityIndicator size="large" />
      </View>
    ) : (
     <View style={{flex:1,flexDirection: "column", padding: 10 }}>
                {this.renderItem}
            </View> );
```

Comment: @TeodorusTeodorus  If my answer was helpful, would you choose the 'V' sign and arrow?

Comment: sorry but it also not working, i think this problem is not related to conditional operator, because i try to remove it and it just become "<View style={{flex:1,flexDirection: "column", padding: 10 }}>
                {this.renderItem}
            </View> );", but it also not working. I think the problem is in renderItem, but I cannot resolve it